# React-native is not updating changes in android

Tags: android, react-native, updating

When i try to run on android the latest code is not updating. However, i can see the changes on **IOS** device. 
I tried reseting the cache `react-native start --reset-cache`, i reinstalled watchman.But nothing helps me. Could anyone figure it out?

Comment: What do you mean by "latest code"?

Comment: means: for example i added a list view in my project. I am not able to view that list  in android but in ios i can.

Comment: can we see your code snippet of that file??

Comment: Have you enabled live reloading on your android app? Shake your mobile phone once and a debug options menu opens up. Click on Enable Live Reloading.

Comment: @Darsan yes man i have done that. I didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally i got the issue.I run the command `react-native log-android` and i got this error [adb invocation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GW8r.png)

so i link adb with exporting path.

1. `echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.bash_profile`
2. `echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile`

3.`source ~/.bash_profile`

Now code are reflected on android device too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure React Native Server is running. If it is not running than do following

steps :

1) go to project path : cd '/home/himanshu/ReactNative_CLI/DemoApp'

2) Execute this command to start server: "react-native start"

3) if project not running : "react-native run-android"

4) Save file on your editor and you can see the changes on your device / emulator:

Note: make sure you have enabled reload on device / emulator :

- To enable reload on emulator: press "ctrl+M / Cmd + M / R,R(Press R Twise)"
- To enable reload on real device : Shake your phone : it will show popup to reload.